# How to access a specific fieldset in a form in my model class?

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform, fields

I am using the code below for getting form values:

```
$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```

However, when I use `json_encode`, it encodes all the form fields I use. How do I select 
fields in the form from a specific fieldset? I have 2 fieldsets in my Form, the original one and the other fieldset named 'reportFilters'. I can only use the getFieldset in my View Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my custom fields were all from the database, I had a workaround with this issue, and that is to create a new associative array, and load the custom fields from the database and then assign values of the custom fields coming from what I have got from this code.

```
$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'array');
```

The only thing that made this difficult is I was supposed to create the form as dynamic as possible.

Answer (score 3):

When using the above command to retrieve server request data, the form fields are organized in a key/value array.  Which fieldset is irrelevant to retrieving the data from the array, simply use the form field name given in the XML form definition file.  So, if you had a field called 'first_name' you would access like so regardless of which fieldset:

```
$data = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'array');
$data['first_name']
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: is there any way for the generated form together with my custom fields be retrieved to the model?